# Install firefox without locales?

Tags: firefox, locale, mozilla

I wish to install Mozilla Firefox without having to install non-english locales. They occupy space and need to be downloaded with each update which seems a waste of storage and bandwidth.

Comment: Which ones did you install? The packages in the Ubuntu archive have the locale packs all split out separately, and they are not all installed by default.

Comment: I was using eOS, based on ubuntu 14.04 and when I installed firefox on it  with the package manager (apt-get), it came with a lot of locales (don't remember specifically) and I was prompted to re-install these with every update.

Comment: Then simply remove the ones you don't want. They only get installed in Ubuntu when you enable those locales in the language selector in settings. If you're using elementary, I don't know. It's not an official derivative, so it's off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the locale packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox-locale-*
```

This **does not** touch the core `firefox` package.

I just tested it, Firefox launches perfectly fine after purging all locale packages. It has an English user interface preinstalled. I think it's the South African English locale, but not too sure about that - it's some English at least.

Comment: It will also remove firefox, because at least one locale package needs to be installed, as the English locale is `firefox-locale-en`.

Comment: @dobey Are you sure? Running that with the `--simulate` flag seems not to remove firefox itself... Have no test system which I could mess up currently.

Comment: Well I didn't try it, so maybe firefox will remain, but I guess I'm not sure what it would do without any locales available. Maybe the text will all be blank. :)

Comment: But if you do, Language Support will prompt you to install them next time you open it... Personally I consider this to be a pseudo-problem. If you are so short of space, so those FF-langpacks make a difference, you have a big problem anyway.

Comment: I think this would remove the English locale too. Also won't I be prompted again to install those with the new update?

Comment: @user3832088 I just tested it, it works fine after purging all locale packages. See my edit.

Comment: @dobey Just tested it, purging the locales works fine. See my edit.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson No. Nothing will prompt them to be installed under normal usage. How one would have managed to install more than only a couple to being with, is beyond me. One would have had to explicitly install them all at some point, either by enabling all locales in system settings (which installs a lot more than just firefox locale packages), or by installing the firefox-locale-XX explicitly.

Comment: @dobey: Well, the OP didn't mention how many `firefox-locale-*` packages he has. Yes, _Language Support_ does prompt you to install missing language support (including `firefox-locale-*`) if you open the tool, but only for the installed languages. Maybe you don't consider it to be 'normal usage' to open it. ;)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson It's not considered "normal usage" to install all the languages. It only prompts you to install langpacks for languages you've specifically enabled.

Comment: @dobey: That's what I meant to say - "but only for the installed languages".